# How to print a NSRange in NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog, nsrange

Say my range is created as

```
NSRange myRange = {0,100};
```

How do I print `myRange` in NSLog? The following is not working

```
NSLog(@"my range is %@",myRange);
```

Answer (score 56):

Use `NSStringFromRange`.

```
NSLog(@"my range is %@", NSStringFromRange(myRange));
```

In Swift you can do:

```
print("my range is \(NSStringFromRange(myRange))")
```

Comment: Is `NSStringFromRange(myRange)` the proper way to do it in Swift?

Comment: OK. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`NSStringFromRange(myRange)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromRange).